# Не добавляется новая строка в базе данных

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("bd/users.db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    rez = cur.fetchone()
    userid = message.from_user.first_name
    lvl_def = 0

    reg_cmd = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
        id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                  NOT NULL,
        user TEXT,
        lvl INTEGER
    );
    '''

    cur.execute(reg_cmd)
    db.commit()


    cur.execute("SELECT user FROM users")
    if rez is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO users(user, lvl) VALUES (?, ?)''', (userid, lvl_def))
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"*Вы были зарегистрированы!*", parse_mode='Markdown')

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'*Ваш профиль существует в базе данных!*', parse_mode='Markdown')


    db.close()
```

База данных создает один профиль, а остальным пишет что их профиль уже создан, хотя на самом деле это не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
cur = db.cursor()
rez = cur.fetchone()
...
cur.execute("SELECT user FROM users")
if rez is None:
```

Странно было бы, если бы такой код работал. Получать данные из курсора нужно **после** запроса на выборку из БД, а не до него.

Кроме того, вы не используете `userid` при запросе к БД. Итого примерно так должно быть:

```py
cur = db.cursor()
...
cur.execute("SELECT user FROM users WHERE user=?", (userid,))
rez = cur.fetchone()
if not rez:
```

Comment: К сожалению, он так же выводит else...

Comment: А есть смысл реализовать добавление пользователя через try и except?

Comment: Добавил ещё исправление

Comment: Спасибо большое, твой ответ пометил как верный. Все заработало.

Comment: try/except просто не нужен, если нормально сделать проверку через select. Иногда делают просто без проверки сразу вставку, но это не совсем правильно. Ошибка при вставке может быть не только в том, что такой пользователь уже есть в базе.